# Who bewhitched the Triwizard Cup in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

I want to know.
I honestly love Harry Potter but it just stands out to me.

Answer (score 5):

Fake-Moody (Barty Crouch Jr. impersonating Moody using Polyjuice) admitted that he did it.

> 'Karkaroff's gone? He ran away? But then – **he didn't put my name in the Cup?**'
>
> 'No,' said Moody slowly. '**No, he didn't. It was I who did that**.'
>
> Harry heard, but didn't believe.
>
> 'No, you didn't,' he said. '**You didn't do that – you can't have done –**'
>
> '**I assure you I did**,' said Moody, and his magical eye swung around, and fixed upon the door, and Harry knew he was making sure that there was no one outside it. At the same time, Moody drew out his wand, and pointed it at Harry.

...

> 'You didn't – it – it can't be you –'
>
> '**Who put your name in the Goblet of Fire, under the name of a different school? I did**. Who frightened off every person I thought might try to hurt you or prevent you winning the Tournament? I did. Who nudged Hagrid into showing you the dragons? I did. Who helped you see the only way you could beat the dragon? I did.'
>
> (*Goblet of Fire, CHAPTER THIRTY-FIVE, "Veritaserum"*)